# Dynamo DB Batch Call with LSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table which has customerId and orderId as Primary Partition Key and Sort Key respectively.
I have LSI on CustomerID and ProductID.

Is it possible to make a batch call for multiple ProductIds for a particular customerId?
Is Batch call supported only for key columns ? or it possible to make batch call based on LSI also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BatchGet can only be made on the table, not on any indexes. I think this is because uniqueness of the key is only enforced for the table's key, not any index key.

If you want to return just the specific items for each ProductId and CustomerId, you will have to make multiple query calls, specifying a productId in each.

Alternatively you can query for all the ProductIds between the first and last ProductIds when ordered. i.e. if you need the ProductIds 1, 5, 10, 13, 14, you can query for all ProductIds between 1 and 14 for the Customer.